# Call helper of another module in my module in magento

Tags: magento, helper

How can I call helper of another module in my module?

When I try

Mage::helper('helperclass')->getValueClass('',$id)

It gives me error:

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Helperclass_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp\www\example\app\Mage.php on line 516

The helper class name is Test_Helperclass_Helper_Data.

Comment: and is your helper defined in config.xml, file exists in path app/code/local/Test/Helperclass/Helper/Data.php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the correct way to call a helper, but your error suggests that you've not set up your module properly.  I presume your module exists in `app/code/local/Test/Helperclass`, and that you have enabled your module with a `app/etc/modules/Test_Helperclass.xml` file.

When you call Magento's factories, such as `Mage::getModel()`, `Mage::getSingleton()`, or `Mage::helper()`, you don't provide the full class name, but a reference to the class you'd like to instantiate.

This has the format `modulename/classname`.

In our case, the module name is `helperclass` (doesn't have to bare any relationship to the *actual* name of the module, it could just as well be `foobar`), and our class name is `data`.  So we're essentially calling `Mage::helper('helperclass/data')`, but Magento lets us shorten that down to `Mage::helper('helperclass')`.

We need to tell Magento the rule behind expanding `helperclass/data -> Test_Helperclass_Helper_Data`.  We do this in the module configuration file at `app/code/local/Test/Helperclass/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
        <global>
            <helpers>
                <!-- Here is where we define the mapping rule -->
                <helperclass>
                    <class>Test_Helperclass_Helper</class>
                </helperclass>
            </helpers>
        </global>
    ...
</config>
```